# Why doesn't container element's background-color fill behind contained element's margin?

Tags: css

I understand that the CSS Box Model doesn't color the margin of an element with a `background-color` because the margin is outside of the element. However, why doesn't the `background-color` of a container element color behind the margin of a *contained* element? Shouldn't it fill all of it's space regardless of what it contains (and whether those elements have margins)?

Consider the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #ddd;
    }
    #container {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 400px;
    }
    .contained {
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #a3ddef;
    }
    .contained p {
      padding: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="contained">
      <p>Some text is here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="contained">
      <p>Some text in here too.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I would expect the `background-color`  of the `.contained` elements to butt up against each other vertically. Further, if you add a `border` of width 1px to the `.contained` then the `background-color` of the elements expands to fill the space.

What's going on here?

[Here's a jsfiddle for it](https://jsfiddle.net/asxztwxs/1/)

Comment: Did you forget that `p` have built in margins? - https://jsfiddle.net/xbzb94s1/ I'm not entirely clear what it is you are asking. The border causes the margins to collapse..try searching for "collapsing margins".

Comment: some browsers have a default user agent style. so the P element has a margin given by the browser, by adding `margin:0;` to the P element it closes the gap and therefore the background. consider using this https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ . I always add the following line to the reset file `*{box-sizing:border-box;}`

Comment: [Collapsing Margins](https://www.sitepoint.com/collapsing-margins/).

Comment: No, I didn't forget that `p` has built-in margins. But my `background-color` isn't on the `p`, it's on the container `div` instead.

Comment: Yes but the margin on the paragraph is what is keeping the blocks apart.

Comment: It is all about margin collapsing : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly is the question, but if you are trying to stack the `.contained` elements so that there is no gray space in between them, you have to remove the margin on the `<p>` tags:

```
p {margin:0}
```

This is a phenomenon called margin collapse. It's sort of a quirk where 2 margins that are touching overlap. Instead of getting the sum of both margins, the bigger one is used. In your case, the `<p>` tag margins touch the margin of the `<div>` tags (even though they are 0px), So that margin spills outside the div tag.

If for some reason you still need the margin on the `<p>` tags, set the `<p>` tags to `p {display:inline-block;}`, as inline elements are not affected by this.

see this link for more info:

http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/css/margincollapsing